# Flutter sliding up panel callback

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I use sliding_up_panel 1.0.2 from pub.dev, trying to use onPanelClosed callback.
For example:

```
onPanelSlide: (double pos) => setState((){
   collapseIcon = Icons.arrow_circle_down_rounded;
}),
```

But this same method doesn't work with onPanelClosed, how to use onPanelClosed callback?

Comment: You're not using the same method in your code and in your description : `onPanelSlide` or `onPanelClosed `

Comment: I don't know how to use this method in general

Comment: I need change icon after panel full collapsed

Comment: Just add `onPanelClosed: () => print('Panel Close')` and play with the slider. You'll get what happen and when

Comment: Error: The argument type 'void Function(double)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'.
        onPanelClosed: (double pos) => print('Panel Close'),

Comment: I edited my comment. Check @EyaS answer's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably got confused between the functions, onPanelSlide and onPanelClosed.
onPanelClosed is called when the panel is closed, while onPanelSlide is called when the panel slides.
try to call to onPanelClosed:

```
onPanelClosed: () => setState((){
    collapseIcon = Icons.arrow_circle_down_rounded;
}),
```

Comment: very strange but i tried to use this function in exactly the same way, after restart android studio its work fine, magic, thank you for answer!